# How can I calculate exact total changed LOC of pull requests in a project which uses Azure DevOps (with GitPython)

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, git-diff, gitpython

I have a project which uses Azure DevOps as version control system. I want to get total changed line of code count for every pull request in the project. To do this, I send a request to Azure DevOps REST API to get all pull requests of the project which includes merge_commit id and last_merge_target_commit id. Then, I calculate the diff of these two commits to calculate total amount of changed loc in the pull request with GitPython. Here is the related code piece;

```py
...

last_commit_of_pull_request = pull_request["commits"][0]["commit_id"]
first_commit_of_pull_request = pull_request["commits"][commits_count-1]["commit_id"]
last_merge_commit = pull_request["last_merge_commit"]["commit_id"]
last_merge_target_commit = pull_request["last_merge_target_commit"]["commit_id"]

#? This is a workaround for prs that include rebase action. If the pr is completed, the last_merge_commit in the pr json file is included in real git history. 
#? Else, it is an artificial commit which is not included in the git history.
if(pull_request["status"] != "active"):
    diff_str = repo.git.diff('{}..{}'.format(last_merge_target_commit, last_merge_commit),"--ignore-all-space", "--numstat")

else:
    # Active pull requests which includes only one commit
    if last_commit_of_pull_request == first_commit_of_pull_request:
        diff_str = repo.git.show(first_commit_of_pull_request, "--ignore-all-space", "--numstat")
    else:
        diff_str = repo.git.diff('{}..{}'.format(last_commit_of_pull_request, first_commit_of_pull_request), "--ignore-all-space", "--numstat")

...
```

The problem is that generated diff does not include the last empty line(if there is any) in a change block. This leads to inconsistency between amount of calculated changed loc and actual changed loc. The generated diff has one less + at the end of the change block. For example;

[Diff generated by GitPython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfY4z.png)

[Diff shown in Azure DevOps UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNvA0.png)

How can I calculate the exact changed loc amount of a pull request in this scenario? Alternatively, is there any way to get this information directly from Azure DevOps Rest API?